# Is there a way to input multiple environment variables into a url for testing on Postman?

Tags: automated-tests, postman

I am testing an endpoint in Postman using a url like this, `{{api_url}}/stackoverflow/help/{{customer_id}}/{{client_id}}`.
I have the `api_url`, `customer_id`, and `client_id` stored in my environment variables.  I would like to test multiple `customer_id` and `client_id` without having to change the environment variables manually each time.  I created a csv to store a list of `customer_id` and one to store `client_id`.  When I go to run collection, it will only allow me to add one file.  Is there another way to do this if I want to iterate through my tests to automate them?

Comment: Try the steps listed here: https://community.postman.com/t/capture-json-guid-value-and-save-in-different-variable-for-each-iteration/15902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add both `customer_id` & `client_id` in one csv file. Postman will iterate n times (n = number of csv lines, except header)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use postman.setNextRequest to control the flow. The below code runs the request with different values in the arr variable

**url:**

```
{{api_url}}/stackoverflow/help/{{customer_id}}/{{client_id}}
```

**now add pre-request:**

```
// add values for the variable in an array
const tempArraycustomer_id = pm.variables.get("tempArraycustomer_id")
const tempArrayclient_id = pm.variables.get("tempArrayclient_id")

//modify the array to the values you want
const arrcustomer_id = tempArraycustomer_id ? tempArraycustomer_id : ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
const arrclient_id = tempArrayclient_id ? tempArrayclient_id : ["value1", "value2", "value3"]


// testing variable to each value of the array and sending the request until all values are used

pm.variables.set("customer_id", arrcustomer_id.pop())
pm.variables.set("client_id", arrclient_id.pop())

pm.variables.set("tempArraycustomer_id", arrcustomer_id)
pm.variables.set("tempArrayclient_id", arrclient_id)


//end iteration when no more elements are there
if (arrcustomer_id.length !== 0) {
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
}
```